# abort previous request when current request start in Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, abort

I used this code for DataTable...

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "orderable": false
        }],
    "ajax": {
        url: baseURL + checkVal,
        type: "post",
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                xhr.abort(); //abort all current request here
            };
            return xhr;
        },
        error: function () {
            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
            $("#table").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
        }
    },
    'initComplete': function (settings, json) {
        //code here
    }
});
```

when I abort it will abort all current request... I want to stop all previous request when current request start running ... How to do that...

I used your all code which is posted in answer. But I can't get any value of **settings.jqXHR** or **settings.jqXHR.abort()** anywhere...

Please help me how to abort all previous request..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

> Hey same problem here, but I managed to fix it. This is how I do it with DataTables 1.10.16

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '/datatable',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function() {
            if (table.hasOwnProperty('settings')) {
                table.settings()[0].jqXHR.abort();
            }
        }
    }
});
```